# How do I duplicate/array a line in a circle using GIMP?

Tags: gimp

I am trying to draw a speedometer with GIMP. Is there a easy way duplicate the line by rotating it about the center?

[image]

Comment: @joojaa I think that one is for adobe software.

Comment: It does not matter what the software is the same method of cloning works in all graphics applications ive ever used. Just adding a tag does not make it a gimp question. Your supposed write that in your question body.

Comment: Try http://registry.gimp.org/node/15534

Comment: @joojaa "It does not matter what the software is the same method of cloning works in all graphics applications ive ever used." It's a good question! Not every body has magically used every tool you've used. Some people just use Gimp. Some people just use MS paint. Some people don't have access to Adobe stuff. Some people don't know what "cloning" is in graphics context. Some people that come here aren't domain experts and come to learn things, not brow beat other people.

Comment: @semusecure if you look you will note that i havent closed the question. I have just complained that you need to write full sentences or you get the wrong results. Also a reminder that the comment section is not a permanent record. Part of the discussion is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Working with symmetries and the flip tool you can avoid some work.

You can use the [multi-replicate script](http://registry.gimp.org/node/22383) to copy-rotate your element as many times as necessary.

You can use the [dial-marks script](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-path-tools/files/scripts/) to create the dual marks directly (as paths, then Select>From path and bucket-fill. See discussion [here](http://gimpforums.com/thread-how-to-draw-this-geometric-pattern-programmatically?pid=22942#pid22942).

Not that this kind of graphic is best done with vector graphics, so Inkscape could be better suited than Gimp.